# No distinguishable border for badges in high contrast mode on dark scheme

Tags: bug, design, badges, dark-mode, high-contrast

I'm not sure that it was intentional, but in high contrast mode (still in beta for SO sites) on dark scheme badges don't have distinguishable borders:

> [image: Dark theme]

Compare with light mode:

> [image: Light theme]

I.e. in dark theme high contrast mode doesn't increase contrast for badges.

Comment: I can see the difference between border and background, but I have to look really closely.